# Expect service methods to return expected values

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to test this method that is called on init. I'd like to be sure each method behaves as expected and will be called with the correct values. I'm not really sure how to do this.

Here's my component and test file

**Component**

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someVar: number;

  constructor(
    private someService: SomeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someMethod();
  }

  private async someMethod() {
    const varOne = await this.someService.methodOne();
    const varTwo = this.someService.methodTwo(varOne);
    this.someVar = this.someService.methodThree(varTwo);
  }
```

});

**Spec**

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

  const SomeServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(SomeService, [
    'addOne',
    'addTwo',
    'addThree',
  ]);

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [SomeComponent],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [],
        providers: [
          { provide: SomeService, useValue: someServiceSpy },
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call each method with correct argument and return correct value on init', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    // Expect methodOne to return 1
    // Expect methodTwo to be called with 1 and return 3
    // Expect methodThree to be called with 3 and return 6
    expect(component.someVar).toEqual(6);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

MethodOne, methodTwo and methodThree are members of someService, so you shouldn't *expect* them to do anything in the spec of SomeComponent, but rather in the spec of someService.

The only test I would write here is to assert that someVar is computed correctly. For that, you would need to spy on methodOne, methodTwo and methodThree and have them return certain values in certain conditions. You can achieve "have methodTwo to be called with 1 and return 3" by using something like:

```
spyOn(component.someService, 'methodTwo').and.callFake((param) => {
   if(param===1){ return 3}
});
```